# What's the best way to use a type assertion with destructuring assignment?

Tags: typescript, formik, destructuring, type-assertion, object-destructuring

I have some code using [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#object_destructuring) as follows:

```
const { values: project, setValues, submitForm } = useFormikContext();
```

Per the [TypeScript type assertion documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) I'd like to use the `as` keyword to tell the TS compiler that `project` will always be the type `Project`.

What's the correct syntax for this? I've tried:

```
const { values: (project as Project), setValues, submitForm } = useFormikContext();
```

but that's invalid.

Comment: By looking [at the implementation](https://github.com/formium/formik/blob/2d613c11a67b1c1f5189e21b8d61a9dd8a2d0a2e/packages/formik/src/FormikContext.tsx) I think you should be using `useFormikContext<Project>()` instead

Comment: Thanks @Teneff. This does exactly what I want - when I hover over `project` now in VScode I can see `project` is of type `Project`. Can you add this as an answer and explain a little further about why this works? Is it that `<FormikContextType<Values>>` makes `<Values>` into a (variable-like-thing) for declaring the type for `values`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following syntax to approach this:

```
const { values: project, setValues, submitForm }: { values: Project; setValues: SomeType1, submitForm: SomeType2} = useFormikContext();
```

You can create another variable, as well:

```
const { values: project, setValues, submitForm } = useFormikContext();
const a: Project = project;
```

Comment: Have added a simple example: https://codesandbox.io/s/voxzc

Comment: Thanks! I like the first example better as it doesn't make an extra variable.

Comment: Yeah, i like it too. I didnt check that you have the typings in your lib. But i think this example more common for other devs.

Comment: You're right - I'll mark this as accepted but upvote @Teneff if they write an answer.

Answer (score 2):

By [looking at the implementation](https://github.com/formium/formik/blob/master/packages/formik/src/FormikContext.tsx) the definition uses [TypeScript Generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html)

```
export function useFormikContext<Values>() {
  const formik = React.useContext<FormikContextType<Values>>(FormikContext);

  return formik;
}
```

it creates a [react context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) and if you call the hook as:

```
useFormikContext<Project>()
```

*probably* not only the values will be of type `Project`, but also `setValues` would accept only object of type `Project` (unfortunately haven't used the library)

Comment: Thanks! This was the answer I used, but I marked the other one was accepted since other folk may be using libraries that don't use generics.